# Simple Javascript Slideshow from Database Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to create a slideshow out of image paths that I store in a database and create the array using PHP, calling it with the JQuery ajax function. I can successfully call the array, however I am having trouble getting the Javascript slideshow to work. Here is my script:

```
window.onload = slideshow(0);

var i;

function slideshow(dir) {

var d = dir;
i =+ d;

$.ajax({
    url: "comiccheck.php",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(i < 0) {
            i = data.length - 1;
        }
        var comic = data[i];
        $('#comic').replaceWith("<img id='comic' src='" + comic + "' alt='comic' />");  
    }
});
}
```

The function slideshow(dir) is being called in the HTML when the user clicks on an arrow button, returning 1 or -1, depending on the direction. Right now the buttons will only advance the image once in each direction, but not any further. Please let me know of any questions or comments you might have on the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `i =+ d` intended? Shouldn't it be `i += d` ?

Comment: haha wow. thank you. before when I switched it, I would get an error, but that's because I never defined i as a number in the first place. I feel stupid.

Answer (score -2):

Try puting the `window.onload = slideshow(0);` after the function declartaion, you can't call a function before you declared it.

Comment: Actually you can call a function from wherever.